If sets $X$ and $Y$ have at least two elements each, then $X \cup Y \preceq X \times Y$
This is a problem from Derek Goldrei's Classic Set Theory, a book that I am currently working through. This is in a chapter titled 'Cardinals (without the Axiom of Choice)' in case that context is necessary.

If sets $X$ and $Y$ have at least two elements each,
then $X \cup Y \preceq X \times Y$

I've been struggling to come up with an injection to prove this. I understand what it's saying is analogous to saying that $x + y \leq xy$ when $x$ and $y$ are both greater than or equal to $2$, and I thought by writing that proof out I would get some insight into proving the original statement, but that did not happen.
I have written out a few finite examples and of course the injections are immediately spotted, but I haven't been able to form a general function.
Going straight from $X \cup Y$ to $X \times Y$ doesn't seem feasible because there will be multiple ordered pairs for any given element in $X \cup Y$. So I believe there will be some intermediate set(s) that I need to map $X \cup Y$ to in order to eventually map to $X \times Y$ such that all of the intermediate mappings are injections.
I'm not necessarily looking for a full solution, more so a nudge in the right direction. Thanks.

As you could see, the problem is analogous to proving that
$$x+y\leq xy$$
for $x,y\in\{2,3,\dots\}$, so let's look at how we can prove that and use the idea to construct a proof for the claim. Observe that
\begin{align*}
xy
&=x+x(y-1)\\
&\geq x+2(y-1)\\
&=x+y+y-2\\
&\geq x+y.
\end{align*}
Let's use this idea. Fix an element $y_0\in Y$, let $Y_1=Y\setminus\{y_0\}$, and observe that
$$X\times Y=X\times\{y_0\}\cup X\times Y_1,$$
where the union is disjoint, so
$$\lvert X\times Y\rvert\succeq\lvert X\times\{y_0\}\rvert+\lvert X\times Y_1\rvert.$$
Clearly $\lvert X\times\{y_0\}\rvert=\lvert X\rvert$, so, analogous to our original computation for integers, it suffices to show that $\lvert X\times Y_1\rvert\geq\lvert Y\rvert$. As $X$ has at least two elements $x_1,x_2$, the surjection
$$X\times Y_1\to\{x_1,x_2\}\times Y_1,$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases}
(x_1,y), &x=x_1\\
(x_2,y), &x\neq x_1
\end{cases}$$
shows that $\lvert X\times Y_1\rvert\succeq\lvert\{x_1,x_2\}\times Y_1\rvert$. Fix now $y_1\in Y_1$ (which exists as $Y$ had at least two elements), and observe that the surjection
$$\{x_1,x_2\}\times Y_1\to Y$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases}
y,&x=x_1,\\
y_0,&x=x_2,y=y_1,\\
y,&x=x_2,y\neq y_1,
\end{cases}$$
shows that
$$\lvert\{x_1,x_2\}\times Y_1\rvert\succeq\lvert Y\rvert.$$
Putting this all together we have that
\begin{align*}
\lvert X\times Y\rvert
&\succeq\lvert X\times\{x_0\}\rvert+\lvert X\times (Y\setminus\{y_0\})\rvert \\
&=\lvert X\rvert+\lvert X\times (Y\setminus\{y_0\})\rvert \\
&\succeq\lvert X\rvert+\lvert \{x_1,x_2\}\times (Y\setminus\{y_0\})\rvert \\
&\succeq\lvert X\rvert+\lvert Y\rvert,
\end{align*}
very analogous to our computation with integers.

Consider the Case where $|X|=n$ with $|Y|=1$.
$X \cup Y$ might have $n+1$ elements
$X \times Y$ will have $n \times 1$ elements
Naturally , the given Criteria will not work out.
Hence we must have at least $2$ elements in $Y$.
Consider now the Case where $|X|=2$ with $|Y|=2$
$X=\{A_1,A_2\}$ with $Y=\{B_1,B_2\}$ where common elements might occur.
Given assertion is true.
Now use Induction to add more elements to either $X$ or $Y$
$X=\{A_1,A_2,\cdots\}$ with $Y=\{B_1,B_2,\cdots\}$ where common elements might occur.
Given assertion will continue to be true.
This Hint Outline will work out.

I'll indicate how to get a strict inequality when each set has cardinality at least $3.$  (The other case is not difficult. )
Let $a,b,c$ be elements in $X,$ and $d,e,f$ elements in $Y.$
Note that $(X×\{d\})\cup (\{a\}×Y)\subsetneq X×Y,$ because none of $(b,e),(b,f), (c,e),$ and $(c,f)$ are in $(X×\{d\})\cup (\{a\}×Y).$
And, $(X×\{d\})\cap (\{a\}×Y)=(a,d).$
And, of course $\mid X×\{d\}\mid =\mid X\mid.$

So, we have $\mid X\cup Y\mid =\mid X\mid +\mid Y\mid-\mid X\cap Y\mid\lt\mid X\mid+\mid Y\mid-1+4\le\mid X×Y\mid. $


Don't overcomplicate. Picture $X\times Y$ as a rectangular array of dots. A row of dots is isomorphic to $X$; a column of dots is isomorphic to $Y$. That almost does it, but there's a slight hitch: the row of dots and the column of dots overlap. Fortunately, they have only one dot in common; and because $X$ and $Y$ each have at least two elements, the row and the column don't cover all the dots, there is at least one dot left over. Give the contested dot to $X$ and give an uncovered dot to $Y$.
